# Why Drools business-central throw marshalling exception during startup

Tags: deployment, wildfly, drools, marshalling

I've got an error: "Failed to bootstrap errai marshalling system!" during Wildfly 24.0.1.Final deployment of Drools business-central.war file version 7.73.0-Final downloaded from official website. I am using Temurin JDK 17.0.6 on MacBook Pro, ARM Apple M1 Pro, MacOS 13.4.1 (22F82)

```
Failed to bootstrap errai marshalling system!
org.jboss.errai.marshalling.client.api.exceptions.InvalidMappingException: there is no custom mapping or default no-arg constructor to map: org.optaplanner.core.api.score.buildin.hardsoftdouble.HardSoftDoubleScore
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.jboss.errai.marshalling.rebind.api.impl.defaultjava.DefaultJavaDefinitionMapper.map(DefaultJavaDefinitionMapper.java:167)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.jboss.errai.marshalling.rebind.DefinitionsFactoryImpl.loadCustomMappings(DefinitionsFactoryImpl.java:383)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.jboss.errai.marshalling.rebind.DefinitionsFactoryImpl.<init>(DefinitionsFactoryImpl.java:126)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.jboss.errai.marshalling.rebind.DefinitionsFactorySingleton.newInstance(DefinitionsFactorySingleton.java:41)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.jboss.errai.marshalling.rebind.DefinitionsFactorySingleton.<clinit>(DefinitionsFactorySingleton.java:26)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.jboss.errai.marshalling.server.MappingContextSingleton$4.<init>(MappingContextSingleton.java:190)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.jboss.errai.marshalling.server.MappingContextSingleton.loadDynamicMarshallers(MappingContextSingleton.java:189)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.jboss.errai.marshalling.server.MappingContextSingleton.<clinit>(MappingContextSingleton.java:84)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.uberfire.backend.server.io.object.ObjectStorageImpl.initializeMarshaller(ObjectStorageImpl.java:122)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.uberfire.backend.server.io.object.ObjectStorageImpl.init(ObjectStorageImpl.java:44)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.guvnor.structure.backend.repositories.git.GitMetadataStoreImpl.init(GitMetadataStoreImpl.java:61)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
```

How can I solve that if I don't have access to sources?

I wanted to deploy Drools business central according this article https://asbnotebook.com/set-up-drools-business-central-and-kie-server-on-wildfly/ but I am stuck on error during deployment war file to Wildfly.